# Less-than operator vs Math.Abs() to check for negative value

Tags: c#

In the example below, is there any advantage (performance wise) to using the less than ( < ) operator to check if a value is negative compared to using Math.Abs?

```
int value = 0;

if(value < 0){
    // Value is negative
}

if(Math.Abs(value) != value){
    // Value is negative
}
```

Comment: I doubt the difference will be noticeable but the C# operator ```<``` is faster than the .NET Framework method ```Math.Abs```. Why don't you test it yourself?

Comment: Using ` < ` vs ` != ` makes no difference to the processor.  So doing something extra, then compare is always going to be slower.

Comment: @JohnHarper you're kidding, or? What expresses "negative" better: "less than 0" or "not equal to its absolute value"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looking at the source code of `Abs`:

```
  public static int Abs(int value) {
      if (value >= 0)
          return value;
      else
          return AbsHelper(value);        
  }
    
  private static int AbsHelper(int value) {
      Contract.Requires(value < 0, "AbsHelper should only be called for negative values! (hack for JIT inlining)");
      if (value == Int32.MinValue)
          throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_NegateTwosCompNum"));
      Contract.EndContractBlock();
      return -value;
  }
```

It will not only be slower but will also have different behavior to call `Math.Abs` instead of `<` and will throw an exception for value `Int32.MinValue` (-2147483648)

Answer (score 1):

The less-than operator is faster:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace so64610522
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool IsNeg1(int a)
        {
            return a < 0;
        }

        static bool IsNeg2(int a)
        {
            return (Math.Abs(a) != a);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var min = -300000000;
            var max = +300000000;
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = min; i < max; i++)
            {
                IsNeg1(i);
            }
            var t1 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            sw.Restart();
            for (int i = min; i < max; i++)
            {
                IsNeg2(i);
            }
            var t2 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} vs {1}", t1, t2);
        }
    }
}
```

On my machine this outputs

```
1761 vs 2608
```

so the less-than operator is ~50% faster than the abs method.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to compare performance is to see how many operations can be achieved per timespan. You could easily write something to compare these two methods (notwithstanding that they give different results!)

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    var value = 100;
    var result1 = await Perf(() => {var x = value < 0;});
    Console.WriteLine(result1); 
    
    var result2 = await Perf(() => {var x = Math.Abs(value) != value;});
        
    Console.WriteLine(result2);
}

static async Task<int> Perf(Action act)
{
    int numOps = 0;
    
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    
    await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(2000),Task.Run(() => {
        while(true)
        {
            act();
            numOps++;
        }
    },cts.Token));
    
    cts.Cancel();
    
    return numOps;
}
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tgascX

The results I got in 2 seconds were:

- `<` = 501726838
- `Math.Abs` = 339073849

Making using `<` about 48% quicker